# How to delete files based older than specified date in Azure Data lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have data folders created on daily basis in datalake. Folder path is dynamic from JSON Format

[image: JSON File with Parameters]

**Source Folder Structure**

`SAPBW/Master/Text`

**Destination Folder Structure**

```
SAP_BW/Master/Text/2019/09/25
SAP_BW/Master/Text/2019/09/26
SAP_BW/Master/Text/2019/09/27
..
..
..
SAP_BW/Master/Text/2019/10/05
SAP_BW/Master/Text/2019/09/06
SAP_BW/Master/Text/2019/09/07
..
..
SAP_BW/Master/Text/2019/09/15
SAP_BW/Master/Text/2019/09/16
SAP_BW/Master/Text/2019/09/17
```

I want to delete the folders created before 5 days for each folder of sinkTableName

So, in DataFactory, i have  Called the folder path in a for each loop as

```
@concat(item().DestinationPath,item().SinkTableName,'/',item().LoadTypeName,'/',formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-5),item().LoadIntervalFormat),'/')"
```

[image: Datafactory for each loop]

Need syntax to delete the files in each folder based on the JSON.

Unable to find the way to delete folder wise and setup the delete activity depending on the dates prior to five days from now

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are doing a concatenation , which I think is the way to go . But I see that you are using the expression `formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-5)` , which will give you something like 2019-10-15T08:23:18.9482579Z which i don't think is desired . I suggest to try with `@formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-5) ,'yyyy/MM/dd')`. Let me know how it goes .

Comment: I have the yyyy/mm/dd already in my code
formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-5),item().LoadIntervalFormat))
where LoadIntervalFormat is 'yyyy/MM/dd'
Redirecting to an updated thread 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58462309/delete-nested-date-folder-getdate-5-date